# Prevent TouchableOpacity onpress when not mid-press?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

right now when I press my touchableopacitys very quickly, it will stack up a bunch of calls to the onpress callback and then execute them over time.  What I want instead is to be able to prevent further callbacks while the touchableopacity is "pressed" or faded, so that the onpress is only called once for each time the touchableopacity is "down", i.e. one full cycle of fading out then back in.  How would I do this?

Comment: You could use the `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` methods to set an `isPressed` boolean. In your `onPress` method, check if the boolean is already true. If it is, ignore the event and return. If not, handle the event.

Comment: Maybe you can disable the button when it's pressed and enable it when callbacks are executed?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is you want to limit your on press callbacks, so that they will only run once .You can use `throttling` with `underscore` library for that: For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     _.throttle(
        this.onPressThrottle.bind(this),
        200, // no new clicks within 200ms time window
    );
  }
  onPressThrottle() {
     // this only runs once per 200 milliseconds
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressThrottle}>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't this merely add a timed delay to the button's activation rather than establishing some one-press logic?